# How to get notified / access "Later" messages with Slack bolt

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm looking for a way to listen (or fetch) all messages a user has marked as "later" together with the status (In progress/Archived/Completed if possible).
I couldn't find anything in the documentation.
Does anyone know how to get these messages with Slack API/ Slack bolt?

Thanks!